# How to accept null/no input in a text box WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know how to accept null/no input from a text box or how to prompt the user to enter a number and not a string.
The window prompts the user to enter values in different textboxes, but if one of the text boxes is left empty then I get an error.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CommonClass.tax = decimal.Parse(TaxText.Text);
    CommonClass.groceries = decimal.Parse(GroceryText.Text);
    CommonClass.water = decimal.Parse(WaterText.Text);
    CommonClass.transport = decimal.Parse(TransportText.Text);
    CommonClass.phone = decimal.Parse(PhoneText.Text);
    CommonClass.other = decimal.Parse(OtherText.Text);
    SaveMoneyWindow SMW = new SaveMoneyWindow();
    SMW.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Back in the old good days, I used to set the WFP field value to an empty string initially.

Comment: When the text is empty you will get an exception while parsing. You could try to add `decimal.Parse(TaxText.Text) ?? 0` in every line

Comment: Or `var success = decimal.TryParse(TaxText.Text, out CommonClass.tax);`. Notify the user when it returns false.

Comment: @RobertHarvey System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: You may want to take a look at [How to: Implement Binding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `TextBox` is empty before you try to parse the value:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CommonClass.tax = TryGetValue(TaxText.Text);
    CommonClass.groceries = TryGetValue(GroceryText.Text);
    CommonClass.water = TryGetValue(WaterText.Text);
    CommonClass.transport = TryGetValue(TransportText.Text);
    CommonClass.phone = TryGetValue(PhoneText.Text);
    CommonClass.other = TryGetValue(OtherText.Text);
    SaveMoneyWindow SMW = new SaveMoneyWindow();
    SMW.Show();
    Close();
}

private static decimal TryGetValue(string s)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(s, out decimal value))
            return value;

        MessageBox.Show($"{s} in an invalid value");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented this, but when I click on the button to submit then I cannot re-enter the value. It just closes the window. How do I fix that?

Comment: It's your code that closes the window. When do you not want to close it? Implement this check in your code.